# JQuery click event works only once in a <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I make this click just work once in my html?

right now it is working in all tr from the table, should work just once after this not anymore.

```
$("#example tbody tr").on("click", function() {
   $(this).addClass('row-selected');            
})
```

Comment: Change `.on()` to `.one()`

Comment: Are you wanting one click per row or just one click on the table? if the latter, then `.one` won't work and you will need to unbind the rest of the clicks (see my answer below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to unbind the click event after your first click:

```js
var tr = $("tr");
tr.one("click", function() {              // this means that you can only click each row once
  $(this).toggleClass('row-selected');
  tr.off('click');                        // this will unbind the click event from the rest of the rows
})
```

```css
.row-selected td {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `one` instead of `on`. more about `one` http://api.jquery.com/one/

```
("#example tbody tr").one("click", function() {
   $(this).addClass('row-selected');            
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$("#example tbody tr").one("click", function() {
   $(this).addClass('row-selected');            
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your click event callback you can remove the event. Just pass the event through as a parameter.

```
$("#example tbody tr").on("click", function(event) {
   $(this).addClass('row-selected'); 
   event.target.onclick = null;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try This
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 $(document.body).on("click", '#example tbody tr', function() {
  $(this).addClass('row-selected');            
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the on("click" to one("click"

Try the below

```
$("#example tbody tr").one("click", function() {
$(this).addClass('row-selected');            
})code here
```

or you can try checking out this page [bind unbind](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/click-once-and-unbind/)

Here is the example they use on that site I linked.

```
$('#my-selector').bind('click', function() {
   $(this).unbind('click');
   alert('Clicked and unbound!');
});
```

Comment: bind and unbind are deprecated in v3 - use on and off